# Installed ubuntu on USB and want to resize the main partition

Tags: partitioning, format, mountpoint

I installed ubuntu using the default settings on my USB 3 flash drive... but later on I found that it partitioned only 14GB for ubuntu main partition (dev/sdc2)243MB for /boot mountpoint,dev/sdc1 (already the 138 are used) and the rest of 17GB (!!!) was partitioned as a swap file! I have 16GB of ram so I would like to shrink the swap file to 1,2 GB and use the rest to resize the main partition (does the /boot mountpoint need more or a few MB are good? )

Disks app shows my usb in 2 ways

1st way as a USB device (labeled 32GB thumb drive)

Of which 255MB are labeled as "Filesystem Partition 1 ext2" /dev/sdc1

-kb labeled as "Partition 2" /dev/sdc2

31GB labeled as "Free Space" /dev/sdc/ and containts: Unallocated Space

2nd way its displayed as two seperate "devices" which are labeled as "14 GB block device" /dev/ubuntu-vg/root, Contents Ext4(version1) -mounted Filesystem root and the other labeled as "17 GB block Device" /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_q, Contents: Swap(version 1) -active.

pvdisplay outputs the following:

```
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdc5
VG Name               ubuntu-vg
PV Size               29,20 GiB / not usable 2,00 MiB
Allocatable           yes 
PE Size               4,00 MiB
Total PE              7474
Free PE               12
Allocated PE          7462
PV UUID               yfeuSi-lj22-DMaN-HXCi-qJNP-8ptg-22T7Da
```

Please give your answer to how to resize my main partition as dumped down and analytical (step by step) as possible cause I am a linux noob :P

**EDIT:**

The output of lsblk is as follows:

```
sdc                     8:32   1  29,4G  0 disk 
├─sdc1                  8:33   1   243M  0 part /boot
├─sdc2                  8:34   1     1K  0 part 
└─sdc5                  8:37   1  29,2G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   252:0    0  13,2G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:1    0    16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with fdisk ? It's already installed by default on ubuntu system.

```
fdisk /dev/sd*
```

Where * is the letter of your disk. When you entered in fdisk type "m" to show the commands.

Otherwise, you could try to install gparted to do with a GUI (more easier) but you need to install it first:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install gparted
```

After you will be able to launch gparted from your applications and it's very easier to edit with it (right click with your mouse and "resize" on the correct partition.)

Then, the /boot parition contains the GRUB configuration, the kernel with their System.map, ... I think ~ 100MB or 200MB is enough so 243MB is Ok.

Comment: I am afraid to use fdisk incase I format anything I shouldnt instead of resizing it... as for Gparted its kinda strange when I load /dev/sdc (29 GB) it has dev/sdc1 with filesystem ext 2 and  mountpoint: /boot and flags: "boot" size 243mb thats ok... but then has a dev/sdc2/ with filesystem: "extended" mountingpoint: - size:29.2GB used - unused - flags- and the resize option is triggered off,  under this (as a branch) there is dev/sdc5  with filesystem: lvm2 pv mountpoint: ubuntu-vg size 29GB used 29.15 and unused 48 MB flags: lvm this one I can resize

Comment: but I am afraid to do so because its basically a sandwich of my main partition and the swap file.... so I am afraid of doing somehting to the main partition I shouldnt do... the graphi shows like the blue rectangle covering all the space (/dev/sdc2) and the brown one contained in it (/dev/sdc5)

Comment: Could you give the output of the command lsblk it will be more easier to understand.

Comment: I edited my main post and added the output you asked.

Comment: I  don't really know LVM partitions but I  have found others topics like  this one:  http://bit.ly/1WU55G1

Comment: Ok I used LVM (logical volume management) app as in the thread I unmounted the swapfile and deleted it... now I am able to increase the size of the root partition (as shown in that thread -the post with the blie cilinder screenshot- but) I when I try to accept

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks to @monitor35 who provided me with a helpful link which didnt had exactly what I was looking for but was resource rich enough to point me to the right direction, so Ill tell you what I did in case an other newbie will face the same challenge as me.

What I did is 1st to make sure that my swap file was not in use (otherwise data loss is imminent and maybe the entire installation would suffer)

You can do that either by checking the resource tab on the "Monitor" app already installed in ubuntu or by Ctrl + Alt (left) + T to open the console  and type $  free -m  (without the dollarsign :P I put it there just for orientation)

then what I did is to unmount the swap image (otherwise LVM cant do anything to it)

I did that by entering the console code $ sudo swapoff -a

Then I open LVM I go to logical disks and select the swap partition and simply click on the "remove logical volumes" button and just like that the swap folder is gone.

Now my problem was how to add the unallocated memory (gained from the swap deletion) on my main root partition...

I couldnt do that with LVM because despite the "resize" option being available it couldnt do anything to the root partition because it is already mounted (obviously) and cant be unmounted while still running it...

so rebooted the computer and I used the UBUNTU liveDVD I had to run an other instance of ubuntu on the fly in there I installed LVM again and now could resize my partition from 14GB it was to 29GB and left 2.3GB for making a new swap folder.

I did that using GParted app I just selected the 2,3GB unallocated space (shrank it to 2GB so that I have 300 MB unallocated just because I am superstitious and want linux to have some extra space to do what it would like with it :P ) and created a new partitions with a lynux_swap format.

And everything works now :)